# How to animate list item like whats app?

Tags: android, animation, android-listview, popup

> I want ti implement some list animation like whats app.
>
> In my list item each row contains profile pick and name.
>
> When user click the profile pick i want to show profile pick with some
>   pop up animation like android.
>
> I am googling and implement app it display pop up.
>
> But i want to start pop up form clicked image and also pop down like
>   whats app.
>
> If any body know the solution please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Such animations are called as SceneTransitionAnimation.
You can read the google documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html).
Search and read "**Start an activity with a shared element**" section in the above link